# Sudoku Solver in Python Using Backtracking

Tags: python

I wrote a Sudoku solver in Python and would love any feedback you can give on anything you see fit - the code, the solution, layout, coding principals, format etc.

The program awaits input of an 81 character string representing game data (zero is a blank space) like the below which is an 'evil' Sudoku game from an online website

> 010000370000006082000400000003510000700908003000023900000004000820300000065000010

The solver then identifies any certain values in the game based on this configuration as well as identifying viable values for every unfilled box.  A backtrack is the performed to reach either a solution or identify an impossible puzzle.
The solution (or impossible puzzle) is printed to the screen at the end.

thanks :)

````
class Cell:
    """defines an individual cell in a sudoku puzzle"""
    def __init__(self,box,row,column,value):
        self.box = box
        self.row = row
        self.column = column
        self.value = value
        
        if value == 0:
            self.value = ' '
            self.viable_values = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
                
class SudokuPuzzle:
    """defines an entire sudoku puzzle grid"""
    def __init__(self,puzzle_string):
        self.data_map = []

        if not self.parse_data_string(puzzle_string):
            raise ValueError('Puzzle string parse failed')
        if not self.validate():
            raise ValueError('Invalid game configuration passed')
            
    def parse_data_string(self,passed_string):
        """ingests passed puzzle string into Cell objects"""      
        if len(passed_string) != 81:
            raise ValueError("Passed string not 81 characters long")
            return False
        
        self.data_map = []
        r,c,b = 1,1,1 #row, col, box

        box_col_1,box_col_2,box_col_3 = 1,2,3 
        offset = 0 #offset increments by 3 at the 4th row and 3 again at the 7th row, used to work out which 'box' we are in
        
        for i in passed_string:
            try:
                cell_data = int(i)
            except:
                raise ValueError("Non interger present in game string")
                return False
                   
            # to calculate which of the 9 boxes (3x3 grids) this cell is in
            if r > 6:
                offset = 6
            elif r > 3:
                offset = 3
                
            if c > 6:
                b = box_col_3+offset
            elif c > 3:
                b = box_col_2+offset
            else:
                b = box_col_1+offset

            new_cell = Cell(b,r,c,cell_data)
            self.data_map.append(new_cell)
            #if we reach end of the column, reset colum to 1 and increment row by 1
            if c == 9: 
                c = 1
                r += 1
            else:
                c += 1
                
        return True
                        
    def validate(self):
        """checks that puzzle in current configuration is valid"""
        self.filled_cells = 0
        for cell in [x for x in self.data_map if x.value != ' ']:
            self.filled_cells += 1
            for other_cell in [y for y in self.data_map if y != cell and y.value != ' ' and y.value == cell.value and (y.row == cell.row or y.column == cell.column or y.box == cell.box)]: 
                return False
        return True
    
    def show(self):
        """prints Sudoku grid to console"""
        for i in self.data_map:
            print(i.value,end=' ')
            if i.column == 3 or i.column == 6:
                print('|',end=' ')
            if i.column == 9:
                print('')
            if (i.row == 3 or i.row == 6) and i.column == 9:
                print('------+-------+------')

        print('Filled cells:',self.filled_cells)

    def solve(self):
        """identifies solution to current puzzle firstly through deductions, then backtracking"""
        change_made = True

        while change_made:
            change_made = False
            self.__deductions()
                
            for cell in [x for x in self.data_map if x.value == ' ']:
                if len(cell.viable_values) == 1:
                    cell.value = cell.viable_values.pop()
                    change_made = True
                    
        if self.validate() and self.filled_cells != 81:
            self.__backtrack()
            
        if self.validate() and self.filled_cells == 81:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __backtrack(self):
        """creates a new SudokuPuzzle object to work through backtrack until every viable value for every cell has been evaluted."""
        cell_count = 0
        temp_game = SudokuPuzzle(self.export())
        empty_cells = [] #creates a list of just empty cells for working through
        temp_vv = [] #creates a list of 'set' for each cells viable values.  Maintains same index as empty_cells.  Ensure we can re-set the viable-values if we backtrack
        for cell in [x for x in temp_game.data_map if x.value == ' ']:     
            temp_vv.append(cell.viable_values.copy())
            empty_cells.append(cell)

        while True:
            if cell_count < 0:
                print('Exhausted all viable values, unsolved')
                return
            #if there are no further viable values for this cell, reset the viable values, reset the cell value and step back 1
            if len(empty_cells[cell_count].viable_values) == 0:
                empty_cells[cell_count].viable_values = temp_vv[cell_count].copy()
                empty_cells[cell_count].value = ' '
                cell_count -= 1
            #assign cell a value from viable_values list, update neighbouring viable values
            else:
                empty_cells[cell_count].value = empty_cells[cell_count].viable_values.pop()
                temp_game.__eliminate_nonviable_values_based_on_neighbour_values(empty_cells[cell_count])
                            
                if temp_game.validate():
                    if temp_game.filled_cells == 81:
                        self.parse_data_string(temp_game.export())
                        return
                    else:
                        cell_count += 1          
           
    def __deductions(self):
        """for each row, box and column, identify any viable values that cannot exist based on neighbouring row/box/column and remove them"""
        for cell in [x for x in self.data_map if x.value == ' ']:
            self.__eliminate_nonviable_values_based_on_neighbour_values(cell)
            viable_values_in_row = []
            viable_values_in_col = []
            viable_values_in_box = []
            for sub_cell in [x for x in self.data_map if x.value == ' ' and x != cell]:
                for sub_viable in sub_cell.viable_values:
                    if sub_cell.row == cell.row:
                        viable_values_in_row.append(sub_viable)
                    if sub_cell.column == cell.column:
                        viable_values_in_col.append(sub_viable)
                    if sub_cell.box == cell.box:
                        viable_values_in_box.append(sub_viable)
                       
            values_to_remove = []
            for cell_v in [y for y in cell.viable_values if y not in viable_values_in_row]:
                for row_v in viable_values_in_row:
                    values_to_remove.append(row_v)           
            for cell_v in [y for y in cell.viable_values if y not in viable_values_in_col]:
                for col_v in viable_values_in_col:
                    values_to_remove.append(col_v)   
            for cell_v in [y for y in cell.viable_values if y not in viable_values_in_box]:
                for box_v in viable_values_in_box:
                    values_to_remove.append(box_v)
                    
            for value in values_to_remove:
                try:   
                    cell.viable_values.remove(value)
                except KeyError:
                    pass

    def __eliminate_nonviable_values_based_on_neighbour_values(self,cell):
        """for passed cell, iterate across all data to identiy which values could be valid values based on existing values in relevant row, column and box"""
        neighbour_values = set()
        for other_cell in [x for x in self.data_map if x.value != ' ' and x != cell and (x.row == cell.row or x.column == cell.column or x.box == cell.box)]:
            neighbour_values.add(other_cell.value)

        for i in range(1,10):
            if i in neighbour_values and i in cell.viable_values:
                cell.viable_values.remove(i)

    def export(self):
        """writes puzzle data to string"""
        export_string = ''
        for cell in self.data_map:
            if cell.value == ' ':
                export_string += str(0)
            else:
                export_string += str(cell.value)

        return export_string
            
def main():       
    string_input = input('Enter numbers from Sudoku grid starting from top left and enter across and down with the last digit being bottom right box. Use zero (0) for empty spaces: ')
    #string_input = '010000370000006082000400000003510000700908003000023900000004000820300000065000010'
    print('Inputted string:',string_input)
    game = SudokuPuzzle(string_input)
    game.show()
    print('')
    if game.solve():
        print('Solution found!')
        game.show()
        print('Solution string:',game.export())
    else:
        print('Solution NOT found')
        game.show()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

```
````

Answer (score 3):

### PEP-8

[PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) is the standard style recommendation for Python. In it, it includes things like how many blank lines, how much indentation, recommendations for variable naming and casing.

There are linters ([Flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/), [Pylint](https://pypi.org/project/pylint/) and others) which check your code against PEP-8 and issue useful warnings. In your case there are several simple and obvious things. You are missing many spaces after commas, many lines are too long and such.

### `raise` returns

You have `return` statements after your `raise`s, which do nothing, the code is unreachable as raise immediately returns from your function to the enclosing error handler (the next `try`, the repl or erroring out).

```
            try:
                cell_data = int(i)
            except:
                raise ValueError("Non interger present in game string")
                return False
```

You should also avoid bare excepts. In this case it's "ok" because you immediately raise, but say I do a keyboard interrupt (`Ctrl-c`) while this line is running. I happen to get `ValueError` rather than the appropriate `KeyboardInterrupt` error. Always catch the minimum that you intend to handle.

### Generators

You are constructing lists in-place using list comprehensions and then looping over them, e.g.:

```
for cell in [x for x in self.data_map if x.value != ' ']:
```

While these objects are not very big (81 elements at most), it should probably be a generator, which only returns the elements it needs when requested and not creating them all in advance. This change is simple and just means changing the brackets.

```
for cell in (x for x in self.data_map if x.value != ' '):
```

### Better docstrings

You have docstrings which is good, but they aren't terribly helpful. Take for example:

```
    def validate(self):
        """checks that puzzle in current configuration is valid"""
```

Great, it checks it's valid, that's in the name of the function, what exactly is it checking for? duplicates in the row/col/box? Say so.

### Unclear comprehensions

Comprehensions are great and concise, but you really have to ask yourself whether:

```
for other_cell in [y for y in self.data_map if y != cell and y.value != ' ' and y.value == cell.value and (y.row == cell.row or y.column == cell.column or y.box == cell.box)]:
```

Is the most readable way of expressing it. Even adding whitespace we end with

```
for other_cell in (y for y in self.data_map
                   if y != cell and
                   y.value != ' ' and
                   y.value == cell.value and
                   (y.row == cell.row or
                    y.column == cell.column or
                    y.box == cell.box)):
```

Which is still not clear to me what's going on. First, we want to filter those that are in the same row, column or box, let's turn that into a method on `cell` called `is_neighbour` or something similar.

```
class Cell:
    ...
    def is_neighbour(self, other: Cell) -> bool:
    """ Checks if ``other`` is in same row, column or box as ``self`` """
        return (self.row == other.row or
                self.column == other.column or
                self.box == other.box)
```

Which makes our generator now look like:

```
for other_cell in (y for y in self.data_map
                   if y != cell and
                   y.value != ' ' and
                   y.value == cell.value and
                   cell.is_neighbour(y)):
```

We can also make `is_filled` a method on cell and use that everywhere:

```
def is_filled(self) -> bool:
    "..."
    return self.value != ' '
```

And now we have:

```
for other_cell in (y for y in self.data_map
                   if y != cell and
                   y.is_neighbour(cell) and
                   y.is_filled() and
                   y.value == cell.value
                   ):
```

Which tells me what's going on a lot more.

Also, instead of looping through here and returning False, we can instead do:

```
if any(y != cell and
       y.is_neighbour(cell) and
       y.filled() and
       y.value == cell.value
       for y in self.data_map):
    return False
```

### Using format

In your show method, you loop through building your array from values, honestly, I would say this is an ideal opportunity to use constants and a format string.

```
# Somewhere at constants level, be that class constant or module constant
# Rather than writing the table out by hand 
ROW = "{}{}{}|{}{}{}|{}{}{}\n"
SEP = "---|---|---\n"
GRID = ((ROW*3)+SEP)*2+ROW*3

# Where you want to use it
GRID.format(*self.data_map)
```

This is a purely stylistic choice, however.

Answer (score 1):

**Simplify Logic**

`b` calculation (get rid of un-needed logic/variables)

```
b = ((c - 1) // 3 + 1) + ((r - 1) // 3 *3) # first half mimics box_offset, second the offset
```

`validation` function. `for cell in [x for x in self.data_map if x.value != ' ']` has 2 `for` loops, but because the later inner loop checks `value != ' '` you could make this a single for with an inner `if`. Then the second inner `for` loop also has 2 `for` loops, but the logic should just be in the loop to reduce iterations

```
def validate(self):
    """checks that puzzle in current configuration is valid"""
    self.filled_cells = 0
    for cell in self.data_map:
        if cell.value != ' ':
            self.filled_cells += 1
        for other_cell in self.data_map:
            if other_cell != cell and not other_cell.is_empty() and other_cell.value == cell.value and (other_cell.row == cell.row or other_cell.column == cell.column or other_cell.box == cell.box):
                return False
    return True
```

**Improve Readability**

`show` function, update `i` to something like `cell`

`Cell` having a `is_empty` function

```
def is_empty(self):
  return self.value == ' '
...
for cell in [x for x in self.data_map if x.is_empty()]
```

`SudokuPuzzle` having a `empty_cells` function

```
def empty_cells(self, other_cell=Cell(0,0,0,10)):
  return [x for x in self.data_map if x.is_empty() and x != other_cell]
...
for cell in self.empty_cells():
...
for cell in temp_game.empty_cells():
...
empty_cells = temp_game.empty_cells()
for cell in empty_cells:
...
for sub_cell in self.empty_cells(cell):
```

**Handle Exceptions**

`SudokuPuzzle`'s `__init__` has the potential to raise an Error but it isn't handled in `main`

```
try:
    game = SudokuPuzzle(string_input)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    return
```

**Full Code:**

```
class Cell:
    """defines an individual cell in a sudoku puzzle"""
    def __init__(self,box,row,column,value):
        self.box = box
        self.row = row
        self.column = column
        self.value = value
        
        if value == 0:
            self.value = ' '
            self.viable_values = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
          
    def is_empty(self):
      return self.value == ' '
                
class SudokuPuzzle:
    """defines an entire sudoku puzzle grid"""
    def __init__(self,puzzle_string):
        self.data_map = []

        if not self.parse_data_string(puzzle_string):
            raise ValueError('Puzzle string parse failed')
        if not self.validate():
            raise ValueError('Invalid game configuration passed')

    def empty_cells(self, other_cell=Cell(0,0,0,10)):
      return [x for x in self.data_map if x.is_empty() and x != other_cell]
            
    def parse_data_string(self,passed_string):
        """ingests passed puzzle string into Cell objects"""      
        if len(passed_string) != 81:
            raise ValueError("Passed string not 81 characters long")
            return False
        
        self.data_map = []
        r,c,b = 1,1,1 #row, col, box
        
        for i in passed_string:
            try:
                cell_data = int(i)
            except:
                raise ValueError("Non interger present in game string")
                return False
                   
            # to calculate which of the 9 boxes (3x3 grids) this cell is in
            b = ((c - 1) // 3 + 1) + ((r - 1) // 3 *3)

            new_cell = Cell(b,r,c,cell_data)
            self.data_map.append(new_cell)
            #if we reach end of the column, reset colum to 1 and increment row by 1
            if c == 9: 
                c = 1
                r += 1
            else:
                c += 1
                
        return True
                        
    def validate(self):
        """checks that puzzle in current configuration is valid"""
        self.filled_cells = 0
        for cell in self.data_map:
            if cell.value != ' ':
                self.filled_cells += 1
            for other_cell in self.data_map:
                if other_cell != cell and not other_cell.is_empty() and other_cell.value == cell.value and (other_cell.row == cell.row or other_cell.column == cell.column or other_cell.box == cell.box):
                    return False
        return True
    
    def show(self):
        """prints Sudoku grid to console"""
        for cell in self.data_map:
            print(cell.value,end=' ')
            if cell.column == 3 or cell.column == 6:
                print('|',end=' ')
            if cell.column == 9:
                print('')
            if (cell.row == 3 or cell.row == 6) and cell.column == 9:
                print('------+-------+------')

        print('Filled cells:',self.filled_cells)

    def solve(self):
        """identifies solution to current puzzle firstly through deductions, then backtracking"""
        change_made = True

        while change_made:
            change_made = False
            self.__deductions()
                
            for cell in self.empty_cells():
                if len(cell.viable_values) == 1:
                    cell.value = cell.viable_values.pop()
                    change_made = True
                    
        if self.validate() and self.filled_cells != 81:
            self.__backtrack()
            
        if self.validate() and self.filled_cells == 81:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __backtrack(self):
        """creates a new SudokuPuzzle object to work through backtrack until every viable value for every cell has been evaluted."""
        cell_count = 0
        temp_game = SudokuPuzzle(self.export())
        empty_cells = temp_game.empty_cells() #creates a list of just empty cells for working through
        temp_vv = [] #creates a list of 'set' for each cells viable values.  Maintains same index as empty_cells.  Ensure we can re-set the viable-values if we backtrack
        for cell in empty_cells:     
            temp_vv.append(cell.viable_values.copy())

        while True:
            if cell_count < 0:
                print('Exhausted all viable values, unsolved')
                return
            #if there are no further viable values for this cell, reset the viable values, reset the cell value and step back 1
            if len(empty_cells[cell_count].viable_values) == 0:
                empty_cells[cell_count].viable_values = temp_vv[cell_count].copy()
                empty_cells[cell_count].value = ' '
                cell_count -= 1
            #assign cell a value from viable_values list, update neighbouring viable values
            else:
                empty_cells[cell_count].value = empty_cells[cell_count].viable_values.pop()
                temp_game.__eliminate_nonviable_values_based_on_neighbour_values(empty_cells[cell_count])
                            
                if temp_game.validate():
                    if temp_game.filled_cells == 81:
                        self.parse_data_string(temp_game.export())
                        return
                    else:
                        cell_count += 1          
           
    def __deductions(self):
        """for each row, box and column, identify any viable values that cannot exist based on neighbouring row/box/column and remove them"""
        for cell in self.empty_cells():
            self.__eliminate_nonviable_values_based_on_neighbour_values(cell)
            viable_values_in_row = []
            viable_values_in_col = []
            viable_values_in_box = []
            for sub_cell in self.empty_cells(cell):
                for sub_viable in sub_cell.viable_values:
                    if sub_cell.row == cell.row:
                        viable_values_in_row.append(sub_viable)
                    if sub_cell.column == cell.column:
                        viable_values_in_col.append(sub_viable)
                    if sub_cell.box == cell.box:
                        viable_values_in_box.append(sub_viable)
                       
            values_to_remove = []
            for cell_v in [y for y in cell.viable_values if y not in viable_values_in_row]:
                for row_v in viable_values_in_row:
                    values_to_remove.append(row_v)           
            for cell_v in [y for y in cell.viable_values if y not in viable_values_in_col]:
                for col_v in viable_values_in_col:
                    values_to_remove.append(col_v)   
            for cell_v in [y for y in cell.viable_values if y not in viable_values_in_box]:
                for box_v in viable_values_in_box:
                    values_to_remove.append(box_v)
                    
            for value in values_to_remove:
                try:   
                    cell.viable_values.remove(value)
                except KeyError:
                    pass

    def __eliminate_nonviable_values_based_on_neighbour_values(self,cell):
        """for passed cell, iterate across all data to identiy which values could be valid values based on existing values in relevant row, column and box"""
        neighbour_values = set()
        for other_cell in [x for x in self.data_map if not x.is_empty() and x != cell and (x.row == cell.row or x.column == cell.column or x.box == cell.box)]:
            neighbour_values.add(other_cell.value)

        for i in range(1,10):
            if i in neighbour_values and i in cell.viable_values:
                cell.viable_values.remove(i)

    def export(self):
        """writes puzzle data to string"""
        export_string = ''
        for cell in self.data_map:
            if cell.is_empty():
                export_string += '0'
            else:
                export_string += str(cell.value)

        return export_string
            
def main():       
    string_input = input('Enter numbers from Sudoku grid starting from top left and enter across and down with the last digit being bottom right box. Use zero (0) for empty spaces: ')
    #string_input = '010000370000006082000400000003510000700908003000023900000004000820300000065000010'
    print('Inputted string:',string_input)
    try:
        game = SudokuPuzzle(string_input)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return
    game.show()
    print()
    if game.solve():
        print('Solution found!')
        game.show()
        print('Solution string:',game.export())
    else:
        print('Solution NOT found')
        game.show()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```